# Append a new field to a form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

How might you dynamically add/delete a new entry field on a form without the use of a partial.

```
<%= f.fields_for :list_entries do |list_entry| %>
  <div id="entries">
    <div class="control-group" id="new_entry">
      <%= list_entry.label :description, 'Description:', class: "control-label mandatory_field"%>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= list_entry.text_field(:description, class: "m-wrap col-lg-8")%>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:;" id="addNewEntry">Add Entry</a>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#addNewEntry').click(function(){
          $('#entries').append()
       });
          $('#entries').on('click', '#list_entry', function(){
              $(this).closest('.control-group').remove();
          });
    });
</script>
```

I'm not sure what to put in the append. If I put the HTML code within append, the `fields_for` `list_entry` does not transfer over. Same thing happened when I used a partial. I do not want to use the cocoon gem either since this is an infinitesimal part of my app.

Any ideas...?

Comment: You need to remember that the erb template in your first code chunk is run on the server to generate raw html.  The javascript in your second code chunk is run in the client and can only work with the raw html - it never sees your rails code that generated the html.  So, when thinking about what you want the javascript to do, you need to look at the html you have on the page and what you might do with it.  In this case you could have a dummy, hidden, bit of html which the javascript clones, changes some attributes, and then appends into the list of fields.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 different possibilities here

1. You can use your append, and do following
   `$(object).append("<input name='somename' value='someval'/>")`
2. Send ajax request to server. Server will respond with view like `respond.js.erb`, in which you can do following

`$(object).append('<%= j(render some_partial_with_field) %>'`

where inside partial you can generate any code you need